# How to pass a json from php to javascript for jqPlot?

Tags: php, mysql, json, jqplot

Here is what I'm struggling with today:

I'm trying to draw a graph using jqPlot library.
The sql query outputs data which is converted to json in php by using `json_encode` and saved in hidden form field. This works fine and the actual field contains:

```
[["2011-12-10 12:01:00",271],["2011-12-10 12:13:05",132],["2011-12-11 12:17:55",388],["2011-12-10 22:03:40",5],["2011-12-11 12:10:54",830]]
```

Then the data from the form is retrieved in javascript by using:

```
var data = document.getElementById("dataarray").value;
```

in order to use it as a data for jqPlot later on.
The `data` variable is correctly formatted and when checked with `document.write(data);`, outputs correct data in json format but whenever I place it inside the `plot1` variable to use data for the graph it throws an error `[object Object]` in Safari and `Uncaught #<Object>` in Firefox.

The whole javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var data = document.getElementById("dataarray").value;  


    var test = [["2011-12-10 12:01:00",271],["2011-12-10 12:13:05",132],["2011-12-11 12:17:55",388],["2011-12-10 22:03:40",5],["2011-12-11 12:10:54",830]];
    var plot1 = $.jqplot("chart_personal_2", [data], {
          title:"Data Point Highlighting",
          axes:{
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          numberTicks: 3,
          tickOptions:{
            formatString:"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
          } 
        },
        yaxis:{
        label: "Elevation(m)",
          tickOptions:{
             showMark: true
            }
        }
          },
          highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
          },
          cursor: {
        show: false
          }
      });
});
```

I even tried `output = String(data);` but it did not work either.
I'm assuming that my `data` variable is an object that cannot be used as source data for jqPlot graph, it needs to be converted to string prior use? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Hope somebody knows how to work it out without, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving it as `String`, but `jqPlot` expect `Array`, so you have to run `eval` on it:

```
var data = document.getElementById("dataarray").value;
eval('data = '+data+';');
```

or better solution: don't save it to hidden input, but make JS variable from php:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var data = ".json_encode($data).";</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you, converting it to an array fixed the issue. I was quite sure that jqPlot is also able to handle string if it is in JSON format, but I can see I was wrong.